# Updating Pivot table by searching type on additional field - Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have 3 tables Users, Languages and Language_User as shown below:

## Users

id

name

...

## Languages

id

language

## Language_User

id

user_id

language_id

type('learn','native')

I would like to update language_id for both the type but depending on the type.

So, if  `$user = User::find($id); and type is native` enter `language_id as 3`(let's say)

similarly, `if type is learn` enter `language_id as 4`(let's say) which comes from the form of type PATCH.

I dont get it how to use this and add extra check for type:   `$lang = User::find($id)->languages()->updateExistingPivot($languageId, $attributes);`

OR

```
App\User::find(1)->languages()->save($language, ['language_id' => $learn]);
```

**How to check for type in pivot table before overriding the data.**

I tried this:

```
public function settings_update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $rules = array(
      'learn'                  => 'required',
      'native'                 => 'required',
      'search_status'          => 'required'
      );

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {

         return Redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator);

    } else {

        $user = User::find($id);
        $user ->search_status        = Input::get('search_status');
        $user ->save();

        $learn_id = Input::get('learn');
        $teach_id = Input::get('teach');

        $lang1 = User::find($id)->languages()->wherePivot('type', 'learn')->attach($learn_id);

        $lang2 = User::find($id)->languages()->wherePivot('type', 'native')->attach($teach_id);

    return redirect('/users/settings');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also manually populate the pivot table of manytomany relations.

Create Model LanguageUser

```
<?php
    namespace App;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    class LanguageUser extends model 
    {
        protected $fillable = ['user_id','language_id','type'];
    }
```

And then populate:

```
public function store(Request $request,$id)
{
    if($result->type=='native')
    { 
        $pivot=new LanguageUser();
        $pivot->user_id=$id;
        $pivot->language_id=3;
        $pivot->type='native';
        $pivot->save();
    }

    else if($result->type=='learn')
    {            
        $pivot=new LanguageUser();
        $pivot->user_id=$id;
        $pivot->language_id=4;
        $pivot->type='learn';
        $pivot->save();
    } 
    else{//}
}
```

Comment: @Murlidhar i'm not too sure but it suits your condition.